# jquery + Scrolling + Check what element is visible

Tags: jquery, scroll

I would like to know if its possible with jQuery to do the following:

**http://jsfiddle.net/AzFJR/2/**

-check which ".main" is visible at the moment and dynamically add ".active" to the corresponding link in the "nav" ?

Regards!

Edit:

I have worked it out using this [Viewport Plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport) and following code:

```
//find what element is in view
var inview = '#' + $('.sectionSelector:in-viewport:first').attr('id'),

//find the corresponding link
$link = $('.mainNav li a').filter('[hash=' + inview + ']');

//check i its already active or not and if not
if ($link.length && !$link.is('.active')) {

    //remove all previous active links and make the current one active
    $('.mainNav li a').removeClass('active');
    $link.addClass('active');    

}

//Start same proccess on every scroll event again
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var inview = '#' + $('.sectionSelector:in-viewport:first').attr('id'),
    $link = $('.mainNav li a').filter('[hash=' + inview + ']');
    if ($link.length && !$link.is('.active')) {
        $('.mainNav li a').removeClass('active');
        $link.addClass('active');    
    }
});
```

Thanks every1 for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if element is visible after scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [jQuery ELEMENT ‘INVIEW’ EVENT plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/in-viewport-event).

```
$('div').bind('inview', function(event, isInView, visiblePartX, visiblePartY) {
  if (isInView) {
    // find link and addClass '.active'
  } else {
    // remove the class
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi again! i tried it with the plugin, but it somehow doesnt work. See my example at http://jsfiddle.net/87uU5/2/. You maybe see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `scrollTo` plugin should do the trick http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html